# Python: Access Posix' locale database without setlocale()

Tags: python, django, posix, internationalization, locale

The setup is a Django based website on an Ubuntu server system with lots of useful information in `/usr/share/i18n/locales`.

The question: Can I access this pool of wisdom *without* using Python's `locale.setlocale()` afore?

The reason: [The docs](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) say, that it is

1. very expensive to call `setlocale()`, and
2. affects the whole application.

But in my case I have a, say, French site (Django handles setting the locale automatically), and I just want to display the name of January in the `de_AT` locale, or format a number like they do in Russia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic library to achieve this is called [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/). Does what I want:

#### Before

```
import locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de')
x = locale.format('%.2f', 123)
setlocale(LC_ALL, '')
```

#### After

```
from babel.numbers import format_decimal
x = format_decimal(123, format='#0.00', locale='de')
```

...and has a good Djang integration gratis.